# Can not load configuration file contact your administrator Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a script macro. When I want run it, it return this error:

> Can not load configuration file contact your administrator

Can some one please tell me where's the problem?
Thank you

Comment: If you don't show your code nobody can tell you where the issue is. Please [edit] your question and add the code formatted as code block.

Comment: My code work well in another poste but when I run it on my poste it does not working and it return this error.

Comment: Again! You need to show your code or nobody can help you. Therefore [edit] your question, add the code and tell us on which line the error occurs.

Comment: As @Peh mentioned, we need the code. A quick google search yielded nothing. Otherwise, you could contact your administrator and check if he/she locked something on your poste